# How to dismiss focused of AutoSuggestBox in Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have a project using AutoSuggestBox, It is working well, however, I have some problems with this control. My problem has 2 question, but I apologize because I don't want to separate them and they are related to each other. Here is my question:

1. I have a AutoSuggetsBox which searches for location, after I chose the result from suggested list, I set the content of AutoSuggetsBox is. But my AutoSuggetsBox think that chosen item as a new query string and raised the text changed event again. How can I do to solve that?
2. I want to dismiss (or unfocus) a AutoSuggetsBox when I tap to other controls. how to do that?

These are my questions, if you are annoyed with its length, i apologize for that. I hope you guys can help me, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using TextChanged event try using QuerySubmitted and SuggestionChosen event it might resolve your problem. 
For your second question when new element gets focused on tap previous is automatically unfocused but if you want to handle it manually then use

```
MYSuggestBox.Focus(FocusState.UnFocused)
```

Hope it helps.